# How to add a WebContent folder to a Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, compilation, web-content

I started porting an old Google Web Tools project into Eclipse Oxygen. I've set it up in a "Google Web Tools" project template and it now compiles and runs.

My problem is that there are a lot of static images and html being left off the compiled project. Looking over other projects, it seems a Web-Content folder might be the ideal place to include these components. Unfortunately this is a feature of "Dynamic Web Application" projects. Is there anyway to add a Web-Content (or similar path) to other Eclipse project types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy:

- open the properties of the project and select 'project facts' and select 'Dynamic Web Project'

[image]

- press apply
- switch to GWT -> web application and change the WAR directory to 'WebContent'

[image]

- apply
- close the properties
- copy everything from the war directory to the WebContent directory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That did it. I did upgrade my project from Eclipse oxygen to photon. When I got to this page, it wasn't displaying the updated plugin list but what I previously installed in Oxygen. I had to manually delete my projects .settings folder to get an updated list to generate.

Answer (score 0):

*WebContent* default directory has been replaced with /scr/maion/webapp since Eclipse 2021, then add *WebContent/* in *Properties, Deployment Assembly, Add, Folder*